# Text entry in MVC architecture

Tags: python, design-patterns, model-view-controller, textbox, wxpython

I am considering how to lay out code for a graphical UI. I'm using Python and WX: it not really the focus of the question here, but let's use it as an example.

I understand the point of MVC, and it's something I have tried to implement before, but I often seem to get in a tangle, interfaces leak and everything ends up looking a bit unhappy, if somewhat working. This time, I want to Get It Right (TM).

The problem I (think I) usually have is the inherent statefulness of UI controls, such as a text entry. In the [WX wiki's MVC example](http://wiki.wxpython.org/ModelViewController), the MVC consists of a "Money" model, and an "add" and "remove" action in a separate controller widget, and uses a *non-editable* text entry to present it in the view.

However, what I would like to achieve is a UI which has an *editable* text entry for a string (let's say it's a "name"). The user can type in the box, which will then cause a list of suggestions to be generated by some back-end. These will be presented in a list in the UI. If the user selects one of these, the entry will be updated with the that value, or the user can keep typing to get more refined suggestions. Confirming (e.g. "enter" or some button) will perform some action on the current value of the entry box. This is basically the same as many web-browsers' autocompletion address bars.

However, this seems to imply that the input text box is part of both the View *and* the Controller, since it both presents the current "name" (either typed or selected from the back-end suggestions) and provides events from the user (a text change event in this case). If nothing else, a naive implementation will end up in an infinite recursion since a modification to the entry will cause an update, which will modify the entry...

This is a cut down example, without the suggestion back-end. The entry box lives in the View, and the Controller can reach in to get the value *from the View*. the `if (self.get_name() != new_name):` avoids recursion, and in this case, since the text comes from this box in the first place, the control never gets updated in the view.

```
import wx

from wx.lib.pubsub import pub

class NameModel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''

    def set_name(self, new_name):
        self.name = new_name

        print("Model name is now: %s" % new_name)

        # name has changed - tell anyone who cares
        # (maybe bailiffs?)
        pub.sendMessage("NAME CHANGED", name=self.name)

class NameView(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title="Name View")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.name_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self)

        sizer.Add(self.name_ctrl, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        self.name_ctrl.SetEditable(True)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def get_name(self):
        '''
        Why does the View have a getter?
        '''
        return self.name_ctrl.GetValue()

    def set_name(self, new_name):

        # check for infinite recursion, but this may need to be aware of
        # more state so we don't throw away useful updates
        # Or perhaps disconnect the event?
        if (self.get_name() != new_name):
            print("Setting name in view: %s" % new_name)
            self.name_ctrl.SetValue(new_name)


class NameController(object):

    def __init__(self, app):

        self.model = NameModel()

        self.view = NameView(None)

        # bind events to wire everything up

        # hmm, this feels a bit wierd - the text entry is in the View,
        # but it's driving the Controller here?
        self.view.name_ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.update_name)

        # subscribe the the model messages
        pub.subscribe(self.name_changed, "NAME CHANGED")

        self.view.Show()

    def update_name(self, evt):
        '''
        Called when the user has set the name somehow
        '''
        # ??? getting the data _from_ the view ???
        new_name = self.view.get_name()
        self.model.set_name(new_name)

    def name_changed(self, name):
        '''
        The model has changed, update the view(s) as needed
        '''

        self.view.set_name(name)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = wx.App(False)
    controller = NameController(app)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Is this the correct way to integrate a stateful UI widget into an MVC-style program? It feels a bit untidy as the widget is part of the "View" and part of the "Controller" at the same time. Because of this, I worry that the checks for "should update" are going to get onerous, code-maintenance-wise, and that concerns are not going to be fully separated, leading to complexity down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does the View have a getter? You need to know what the user writes in the text box. You can use a getter or an argument passed to the callback bound to the event (in this case `wx.EVT_TEXT`). If the toolkit does not provide the method you want (disclaimer: I ignore everything about wxwidgets), you may need to implement it in the view or write an adapter.

Check for infinite recursion: put the check in the model. The state belongs to it so it will feel less untidy there. Also setting the name in the model does not necessarily imply a name change, sending `"NAME CHANGED"` only when the name has actually changed makes sense to me and does not feel untidy or onerous.

```
def set_name(self, new_name):
    old_name = self.name
    self.name = new_name

    print("Model name is now: %s" % new_name)
    if old_name != new_name:
        # name has changed - tell anyone who cares
        # (maybe bailiffs?)
        pub.sendMessage("NAME CHANGED", name=self.name)
```

Binding view events in the controller: this is acceptable in my book. In your code the controller is the only one that knows about the view so it is the only one that can do the binding. Of course there are other ways, but I can't provide a concrete answer without knowing what your book says about it.

Getting the data *from* the view (in the controller): As I said above, `update_name()` could receive the data as an argument, maybe as an attribute of `evt`.

Comment: This definitely helps, but the view is still acting somewhat like part of the controller - is that just how it goes with this kind of UI widget?

Comment: Sorry, now I think your actual question is in the comments of the code. I will edit my answer to address them.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
self.name_ctrl.SetValue(new_name)
```

which triggers a wxEVT_TEXT event

Use

```
self.name_ctrl.ChangeValue(new_name)
```

Which won't trigger a wxEVT_TEXT event

If you need to maintain the insertion point use

```
insertion_point = self.name_ctrl.GetInsertionPoint()
self.name_ctrl.ChangeValue(new_name)
self.name_ctrl.SetInsertionPoint(insertion_point)
```

Comment: That's good to know. However, in this specific case, when the user selects some back-end-provided suggest, I will still need to process the update, as I will want to refine the suggestions. E.g. user types "cat", gets "cat care" as a suggestion, selects it, and suggestions are regenenerated and now it has "cat care for dummies" as a suggestion.

Comment: When the user types an event will still happen

Comment: Sure, but I also need to process changes made by the controller in ways other than typing. This is the focus of the question: dealing with the use of the text box both as part of the View and part of the Controller. As I said, I can mess with events and so on to make it work, but cleanly reconciling the statefulness of the widget with an MVC pattern seems to be tricky.

Comment: @Inductiveload The text box is not part of the controller its only part of the view, the controller calls on the views methods, If the controller has to make changes  from typing or any other means, it tells the model about it.The model then broadcasts to any observer interested in the change, any controller that is observing this change then calls a view method to change the displayed value without triggering a change event. Any other control that also needs updating when this change happens will have a controller or the same controller to call other view controls as necessary.